# Searching for value but replacing sibling with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, search, replace

I have an XLIFF file which I'm using for translating an iPhone App into a different language.

Here's how it looks like:

```
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   version="1.2"
   xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2 http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/os/xliff-core-1.2-strict.xsd">
 <file original="kWallet/Base.lproj/BonusProgram.storyboard"
         source-language="de"
         datatype="plaintext"
         target-language="en">
      <header>
         <tool tool-id="com.apple.dt.xcode"
               tool-name="Xcode"
               tool-version="8.2.1"
               build-num="8C1002"/>
      </header>
      <body>
         <trans-unit id="VNf-SH-yf4.normalTitle">
            <source>Nicht mehr teilnehmen</source>
            <target>Nicht mehr teilnehmen</target>
            <note>Class = "UIButton"; normalTitle = "Nicht mehr teilnehmen"; ObjectID = "VNf-SH-yf4";</note>
         </trans-unit>
         <trans-unit id="bks-T0-HXe.normalTitle">
            <source>Teilnehmen</source>
            <target>Teilnehmen</target>
            <note>Class = "UIButton"; normalTitle = "Teilnehmen"; ObjectID = "bks-T0-HXe";</note>
         </trans-unit>
         <trans-unit id="inq-dy-gMC.title">
            <source>Bonus</source>
            <target>Bonus</target>
            <note>Class = "UITabBarItem"; title = "Bonus"; ObjectID = "inq-dy-gMC";</note>
         </trans-unit>
         <trans-unit id="mub-0G-Dk1.title">
            <source>Bonus Program</source>
            <target>Bonus Program</target>
            <note>Class = "UINavigationItem"; title = "Bonus Program"; ObjectID = "mub-0G-Dk1";</note>
         </trans-unit>
         <trans-unit id="rAv-9a-ssv.title">
            <source>Bonus</source>
            <target>Bonus</target>
            <note>Class = "UINavigationItem"; title = "Bonus"; ObjectID = "rAv-9a-ssv";</note>
         </trans-unit>
      </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

Now I need to do the following:

I have the translations already in a textfile in the following format: 
`"source" = "target"`, for example `"Im App Store anzeigen" = "Show in App Store"`

```
/* Show in App Store Text */
"Im App Store anzeigen" = "Show in App Store";
```

So I'm going to create a script, that reads my text file and calls the xslt transform after every line, passing it the 2 values.

Now I need to find out how to solve the transformation using xslt. Basically it needs to search for `<source> == "Nicht mehr teilnehmen"` and then replace it's `<target>` sibling with the second value that I'm gonna pass to the xslt transformer (In this case `"Stop participating"`)

I think this should be pretty easy, but I unfortunately I have not enough experience with xslt to solve that on my own. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Various questions arise.  Is each source-language string is unique?  Or, can the same source-language string occur multiple different times in multiple different places, perhaps even with different target-language strings?  Also, can the strings in the text file contain quotes, and if so, are they escaped?

Comment: Separately, I'm curious about your workflow.  XLIFF is an industry-standard file format for localization data, and most CAT tools these days support XLIFF for direct processing.  What is your workflow, such that your XLIFF has the source text in both `<source>` and `<target>`, and that your actual localized data is instead stored in some separate text format?

Comment: Each Source-language string can occur multiple times and also needs to be replaced multiple times. Quotes do occur, all escaped like this `\"string\"`

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi The problem is, before XLIFF, Xcode used just usual property files (en.strings for example). We already have those english translations within those files, but when xcode generates new XLIFF files, it doesn't take care of already existing translations within those .strings files. Therefore I need to move ALL the translations from .strings to .xliff just once in the best case

Comment: Are source-target strings all one-to-one matches?  Or can one source string equate to multiple different target strings?

Comment: They're all one-to-one :-)

Comment: Actually I think I found out how to do it. Unfortunately I can't use the variable name (passing it from the command line with xsltproc) like this: `<xsl:template match="target[../source=$source]">` with xslt 1.0. And no Idea how to get started with 2.0. This is all such pain in the ass...

Comment: Variables passed in to a stylesheet or template from outside are declared inside the stylesheet via `<xsl:param>` elements. `xsltproc` knows how to bind values to these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to use XSLT 2.0 or newer, the following approach will work.  Three different features here don't exist in XSLT 1.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0"

    xpath-default-namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <!-- Note the `xpath-default-namespace` line here: this is only allowed in XSLT 2.0 and newer.
        The input XLIFF file itself specifies this URI as the unprefixed namespace for the whole file.
        If we don't specify this as the XPath default namespace, we have to specify element names
        in ugly workaround syntax, such as `*[local-name() = 'xliff']`. -->

    <!-- Parameter for feeding in the path to your translated-pairs text file. -->
    <xsl:param name="transfile-path" select="'DEFAULTPATH'"/>
    <!-- Sample path format: 'file:///C:/Users/[USERNAME]/AppData/Local/Temp/transdata.txt' -->

    <!-- Variable containing whole content of your translated-pairs text file. Replace the file path as appropriate.
        The `unparsed-text` XPath function is required to load plain text (as opposed to parsable XML).
        This function is only available in XSLT 2.0 or newer. -->
    <xsl:variable name="transfile" select="unparsed-text($transfile-path)"/>

    <!-- Newline: this might need adjusting, depending on the newline format in your text file. -->
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#xD;&#xA;'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/xliff|file|body|trans-unit">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="header|source|note">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="target">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- This variable tokenizes the $transfile content by newline,
                then grabs the first line where the source matches the current <target> element text
                (wrapped with double-quotes, just in case),
                then chops off the source portion and stores just the target portion, but with the last " on the end.
                The `tokenize` XPath function requires XSLT 2.0 or newer. -->
            <xsl:variable name="target-string" select="substring-after(tokenize($transfile, $newline)
                [contains(., concat('&quot;', current(), '&quot;'))][1], '&quot; = &quot;')"/>

            <!-- Output the target string, minus that last "  -->
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($target-string, 1, string-length($target-string) - 1)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using a simple text file containing translated pairs in the format you specified, the above works for me.  I've tried to include informative comments to walk through what the code does.

#### Caveat

This assumes that your data is *entirely* one-to-one.  So `"Fussbodenschleifmaschinenverleih"` might appear fourteen times in your translated-pairs text file, but it is *always* and *only* translated as the same target string.  :)

#### Side note

If you or your team have access to a [CAT tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_translation), many such tools include an ["alignment" feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_translation#Alignment_software) or companion application, which can take bilingual data like what you describe, and generate translation memories.  Depending on your setup, that might be easier going forward.

### Update

Based on gasparuff's comments, here's how you would look up the source text from the `<source>` element instead of directly from the `<target>` element.  This involves a single change to the previous code:

```
        <xsl:variable name="target-string" select="substring-after(tokenize($transfile, $newline)
            [contains(., concat('&quot;', current()/../source, '&quot;'))][1], '&quot; = &quot;')"/>
        <!-- The previous version had `current()`, as in, the content of the current
            context element, which is here the <target> element.  I changed that above to
            `current()/../source` to instead get the text from the sibling <source>
            element.  .. here evaluates to the parent of the current <target>, and then
            we look for the <source> child of that parent.  This is often safer than 
            using preceding-sibling::source, or following-sibling::source, since we
            often cannot say 100% that the element we're looking for is *before* the
            current context element, or *after* it. -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input, but unfortunately I'm getting just an empty result :-(. The translations in the .strings file all end with a semicolon (sorry, forgot to mention that), so I replaced the newline variable with this: ` <xsl:variable name="newline" select="';'"/>`. Also, I don't know if I'm calling the xslt correctly. I'm using Oxygen XML Editor right now for that.

Comment: Alright, now it worked. But I found out it searches for the key in the `<target>` tags. This works for now, but do you maybe have a solution where the script looks for content within the `<source>` tag and then replaces the `<target>` tag with the new string?

Comment: @gasparuff, your sample input XML all has the source text in both the `<source>` and `<target>` elements.  If your sample input XML is an accurate representation of your working data, we never need to look at the content of the `<source>` element, since the source text is already right there in the input `<target>` element.  We just need to replace the source text in `<target>` with the target text from the text file.  If your sample input XML is misleading, that's a different issue.  :)

Comment: You're right and your answer is correct :-). Though I didn't think about the case when one of the translations gets changed in the strings file and the xliff file needs an update. This actually should never happen, but I would still love to know how something like that would be done, maybe I'll need it some day in the future :D